# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am getting this NullReferenceException in the second execution of the while loop of the changeColors function.

```
public class myClass {
    Tuple<int,int>[] theArray = new Tuple<int, int>[100];
}

public myClass() {
    theArray = null;
}

public Tuple<int,int>[] findRedPixels(){
    Tuple<int,int>[] myArray = new Tuple<int, int>[100];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {   
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if (graph.pixelMap [i, j].color == "red") {
                myArray[k]= new Tuple<int,int>(i,j);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    return myArray;
}

public void changeColors(){  
    while (true) {
        theArray = findRedPixels();
        foreach (var item in theArray) {

            //error appears here in the second time it executes the while loop
            Console.WriteLine (item.Item1 ); 
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: what is `changeColor`? can you update the question with code?

Comment: updated the question with a simpler version

Comment: what is `findPairsWithCost` ? can you paste the code

Comment: may be `Item1` is null, have you debug and check the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return array from function `findRedPixels` as you have done because that array will already be initialized with `100` elements, try using `List` as it provide you flexibility and you can increase decrease size on fly may be something like this

```
public  Tuple<int,int>[]  findRedPixels(){
            List<Tuple<int,int>> myArray = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            int k = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {   
                for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                    if( graph.pixelMap [i, j].color=="red"){
                         myArray.Add( new Tuple<int,int>(i,j));
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return myArray.ToArray();
        }
```